Is the birth of a Chandala despised or the individual within the body
In Manusmriti chapter 10 verse 39 it states, "The ‘Niṣāda’ woman bears to the ‘Caṇḍāla’ the son called ‘Antyāvasāyin,’ working in the cremation-ground, despised even by out-casts.—(39)"
My question is while some sin would've likely led to this birth why is the Chandala simply despised when he doesn't know what happened? Isn't this contempt wrong? Or am I reading it incorrectly due to translation or lack of full context. I want someone well versed in dharmashastras to answer.
